# Add unique CSS Classes to PHP rows

Tags: php, css

I'm working on a project where one of our tables in dynamically generated via PHP. For some items, the user can "customize" the product while other items can simply be added to the cart. I'm attempting to wrap a unique CSS Class around each option so that I can add a button that displays a unique icon next to each of them.  I'm not sure whether or not to try to achieve this by using PHP, jQuery or through another route. Thanks.

```
$row["orderLink"] = (is_array(getRows($fieldsSQL))) ? "Customize" : "Add to Cart";
```

Comment: You could write a loop with php. Do you want to build a new table each time a button is pressed?

Comment: No I don't need to rebuild the table each time the button is pressed, it just goes to another page.

Comment: Hope that helps a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you like to switch between classes?

```
<?php
      $count = 0;
      $classes = array('one', 'two', 'three');

      for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $count = ++$count % count($classes);
        $class = $classes[$count];
      ?>

       <div class="row <?php echo $class ?>">
         ......
       </div>
```

or something more straight forward a bit more simple.

```
   <div class="row 
    <php
        ++$count;
        if($count % 3 == 0)
        {
            echo "style2";
        }
        else if($count % 3 == 1)
        {
            echo "style2";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "style3";
        }
    ?>
    ">
    ...page_list or product_list output
    </div>

<php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't necessarily need to switch the classes, just need to taget each individually. -Sorry can't attach and image since I don't have a credibility score of at least 10 :(

Comment: Cool, i hope i was able to help you along with your project. =] Have a great day.